# Using EOF in the middle of an input line?

Tags: c, io

For my program, I have a prompt to stdout

```
>
```

and then my program reads from stdin. The prompt loops if EOF has not been reached. I have noticed if I enter something, such as:

```
> bee
```

When I press CTRL-D once, nothing happens. When I press CTRL-D again, my prompt comes up again. And only when I press it a third time, does my program terminate due to EOF. Does this mean there is a problem in my code? Or is this normal behavior?

Heres a simplified version of my code:

```
(fopen used)
(print prompt)
while((fgets(tester, 1026, input)) != NULL) {
   if(there is a # in tester) {
     (print prompt)        
     continue;
   }
}
```

Comment: Problem in which code?

Comment: The `Ctrl+D` (Linux) or `Ctrl+Z` (Windows) must be the first keystroke after a `newline`. But still, I have noticed similar curiosities which I have not been able to resolve.

Comment: this pseudocode mix does not compile, and the only part that seems to parse has a bracket mismatch. please post a minimal, complete example.

Comment: The keyboard state and sequences are "outside" your C program.  So whatever is used to signal end-of-file for `stdin` is platform specific.  Without specifying you computer/OS etc, one can muse if this is normal behavior, but a definitive answer needs more info from OP.

Answer (score 1):

In a unix terminal, CTRL-D does nothing more or less than immediately send all bytes pending in the terminals input buffer.

---

**Background:**

Normally, when you enter stuff into your terminal, that stuff is line buffered, so you can keep editing a line until you are satisfied with it, and then send it to the running process by entering a newline (or CTRL-D, the difference is only that CTRL-D does not add a newline character at the end).

Now, processes detect the end of an input stream by checking whether the `read()` call returned anything. So, if you press CTRL-D on an empty input buffer, the `read()` call returns with nothing, and the process thinks "no more bytes coming out of this stream, I'd better not try again". Afaik, there is no other way to check for the end of an input stream, so all programs that recognize `EOF` on `stdin` do this, either directly or via the standard C library. The later is what you did when you called `fgets()`.

---

**Your case:**

1. The first CTRL-D simply sends the three characters "bee" to your process. The `read()` call within your `fgets()` call returns these three characters, and your `fgets()` implementation checks for a newline character. As it finds none, and as its own output buffer is not full yet, it immediately proceeds to fetch more characters with another `read()` call.
2. The second CTRL-D sends nothing as you have not entered any other characters since your last CTRL-D. The `write()` call returns with no output, the `fgets()` sees that it received zero characters and calls it an EOF condition. So it returns the (mostly buffered) string `"bee"` to you.

   Your program may check whether that string contains a `#` character. But its loop cannot terminate until a `fgets()` call returns `NULL` (there is no `break` statement to leave the loop preliminarily).
3. The third CTRL-D agains sends zero bytes to your process. This causes the first `read()` call of the second `fgets()` call to return zero bytes (the loop is about to be reentered after a successful first iteration). The `fgets()` implementation sees the empty results, and since it finds that it has not yet received any bytes, it returns `NULL`. Your loop condition sees the `NULL` and terminates the loop, which in turn causes your `main()` to return, exiting the process.

---

**TL;DR:**

Yes, this is totally expected behavior, even though it seems rather counter-intuitive. That's UNIX: It's KISS, not necessarily intuitive.